# How to fetch GPS device information through GPRS?

Tags: java

I m currently working on a Vehicle GPS Dynamic web app( Using Java, Eclipse, MySql & Apache) Which fetch all GPS real time Information like location speed etc.. from GPS device which  contain Sim card.

My question is

> "How can i connect to that device ?"

If i'm correct after researching a lot i got answer that socket programming is working here but my doubt is that how can i install server program to that device which communicate with Sim card GPRS and send information through web server.

My sample client program and server program is running successfully in `localhost`.